# Launching an app from Xcode performance

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering if there was a performance difference if you launch an app on your iPhone from Xcode vs starting it up from the phone itself. When you launch it from Xcode it seems to be on a debug "lite" mode in the sense that you are getting data to the console.

Are there any performance differences when you don't launch from Xcode ?

Comment: Has your question been fully answered or do you have more questions? If it has, please select the most helpful answer. If you still have questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are performance differences. You wouldn't be able to put a general number on how big they are, because they depend on a number of factors. The differences can go from not noticeable to significantly slowing down even a fairly simple application.

First you have three different operating modes:

- A release build that is installed to the device directly

  > This will enable things such as compiler optimizations. For exact settings have a look at your project file.
- A debug build run with a debugger attached (e.g. by launching from Xcode)

  > On top of your application missing compiler optimizations because of being built with the debug configuration, the debugger can be an additional performance drain.
  >
  > From personal experience I know that having a lot of breakpoints (especially symbolic ones) or watchpoints, can make things noticably slower. You may experience similar problems if you are doing intensive logging.
  >
  > In some projects debug code is also compiled to work slightly differently than in production. For example if using a logging framework such as [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), you would set a more verbose log level, which can again be more processing work.
- A debug build run without a debugger attached (e.g. by installing through Xcode and launching separately)

  > You will not have any compiler optimizations and still work on `Debug` configuration logic, but your application isn't additionally slowed down by the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Actually there could be a lot of difference between debug and release codes.

By default debug build don't use optimizations but add debug symbols to the binaries created. These two can have dramatic effect on the app performance, size and some.

You can go and look at the project settings file to understand what exactly are the differences.

But again to your question, there could be performance changes between debug and release.